# " + {} using " namespace tag doesn't appear

Tags: asp.net-mvc, e-commerce, ninject

[This is the problem](https://i.hizliresim.com/kX4yVD.png)

As you see above; i want to pass my data to view from repository. While i am binding i can not add name space to Product item. It should appear like that guy doing below;

[This is how he does](https://i.hizliresim.com/bLqdnb.png)

When i tried to generate new type class, suddenly i almost achived it but later i lost it again. I hope you understood me.Thanks for helping me!

You can click on the links to see the photos. Thanks,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I already solved it. The problem was i didn't do CTL + S to save my project at the right points. Thanks,